# How to store file paths and read file paths from hdf5 with h5py?

Tags: python-3.x, hdf5, h5py

I would like to save a very long file path as string in my hdf5 with h5py. I have the following code, but it does not seem to work. When I read the file, the variable does not show the file path.
How to do better, please? Thank you.

```
import h5py

hdf5filename='testhdf5.h5'
hdf5dsetname_origin="/entry/origin/filename"

# create hdf5 file and store a very long file path

with h5py.File(hdf5filename, "w") as h5f:
    string_dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)
    h5f.create_dataset(hdf5dsetname_origin, data='/path/to/data/verylong/verylong/verlong/extralong',dtype=string_dt)           

# read it and check the file path

with h5py.File(hdf5filename,"r") as h5:
    string=h5["/entry/origin/filename"]

print(string)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a dataset to store a small scrap of data is overkill. Attributes are designed for this purpose (sometimes called metadata). The example below accomplishes this task. (I created an attribute with your filename plus a few extra to demonstrate attribute usage for floats and ints.) I added these attirbutes to the root level group. You can add attributes to any group or dataset.) Complete details here: [h5py Attributes](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/attr.html#attributes).

```
hdf5filename='test2hdf5.h5'
hdf5dsetname_origin="entry/origin/filename"
datastring="/path/to/data/verylong/verylong/verlong/extralong"
    
with h5py.File(hdf5filename, "w") as h5w:
    h5w.attrs[hdf5dsetname_origin] = datastring
    h5w.attrs['version'] = 1.01
    h5w.attrs['int_attr3'] = 3

with h5py.File(hdf5filename,"r") as h5r:
    for attr in h5r.attrs.keys():
        print(f'{attr} => {h5r.attrs[attr]}')
```

Output looks like this:

```
entry/origin/filename => /path/to/data/verylong/verylong/verlong/extralong
int_attr3 => 3
version => 1.01
```

Comment: Hi Kcw78, thank you for your help. I hope it is ok to ask some questions.
Why don't you have to decode the string like I had to do?

Comment: Hi Kcw78, thank you for your help. I hope it is ok to ask some questions.
Why don't you have to decode the string like I had to do? Because you don't store it as dataset but as attribute?
Bigger datasets would be stored with create_dataset, right? 
I understand correctly, that my datastring is not root level, but your 'version' key, is?
Thank you for linking the h5py page, I only wished it had some more examples.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I got an error when I had tried to decode your string. I modified that line to `string=h5r["/entry/origin/filename"][()]` and it worked perfectly. Not sure why we get different behavior. I am running Python 3.8.3 and h5py 2.10.0 on Windows. I only use attributes for scalars (ints, floats, strings). You can save arrays, but they should be <64k for performance reasons. Based on `hdf5dsetname_origin`, you created a dataset on this path: `/entry/origin/filename`, where `entry` is a root level group, `origin` is a subgroup and `filename` is the dataset that contains the string.

Answer (score 0):

With some help, I found a solution.

```
hdf5filename='test2hdf5.h5'
hdf5dsetname_origin="entry/origin/filename"

datastring="/path/to/data/verylong/verylong/verlong/extralong"


with h5py.File(hdf5filename, "w") as h5f:
    string_dt = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)
    h5f.create_dataset(hdf5dsetname_origin, data=datastring, dtype=string_dt)

with h5py.File(hdf5filename,"r") as h5:
    print(h5.keys())
    string=h5["/entry/origin/filename"][()].decode('utf-8')
    print(string)
```